# Nested Vue instances

Tags: vue.js

Is there anyway to have nested `Vue` instances? I know about `Vue components` and I use them extensively in my applications but in this use case I have **different applications** (I mean different projects) that are loading inside each other in a page.

For example when I do something like the following:

```
<div id="parent">
  {{msg}}
  <div id="child">
    {{msg}}
  </div>
</div>

...

new Vue({
  el: '#parent',
  data: { msg: 'sth' },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#child',
  data: { msg: 'sth else' },
})
```

But both `msg`'s uses `msg` data of parent `Vue` instance. Here I just want to show an example but in my use case these instances are not next to each other and just somehow relate to each other through `Django` framework (which is not important to notice here).

**Update**

It's not a duplicate question. Person who asked that question doesn't need nested `Vue` instances and just needs components. But I explicitly said that I know about components but need nested `Vue` instances.

**Issue**

According to this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6077), they are not going to implement such behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested vue.js instances/elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345149/nested-vue-js-instances-elements)

Comment: No. This is not possible.

Comment: You need to merge components and routes into one app :)

Answer (score 13):

If you really need to have nested instances, use VueJS `v-pre` directive. You can add `v-pre` to the child app. More details about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre).

```js
<div id="parent">
    {{msg}}
    <div id="child" v-pre>
        {{msg}}
    </div>
</div>
...
new Vue({
    el: '#parent',
data: { msg: 'sth' },
})

new Vue({
    el: '#child',
    data: { msg: 'sth else' },
})
```

`{{ msg }}` for child instance will be "sth else". Note that the nested instance (#child element) is not compiled by vue parent instance because of the `v-pre` directive.

Comment: This works great.  But in this case parent will completely ignore the child instance. Is there a way that child can inherit and/or overwrite stuff from parent instance

Comment: You probably need Vue Components for that.